# How can I change the starting point of horizontal bars in Charts.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to get my horizontal bar chart to display a chart where values range from 50 to 150, but I want the starting point of the bars to be 100, so that values above 100 go to the right of the chart and values below 100 go to the left.

The documentation allows for min and max values, but not for setting a custom starting point. Does anyone know how to do that, is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bars with different orientation can be defined as [floating bars](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6056). Individual bars are specified with the syntax `[min, max]`. This feature was introduced with [Chart.js v2.9.0](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.9.0).

Given the base data being present in an array named `data`, you can generate the desired floating bar data through the method [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows:

```
data.map(v => v < 100 ? [v, 100] : [100, v])
```

Please take a look at below runnable code snippet and see how it works.

```js
const data = [50, 80, 120, 150];

new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'data',
      data: data.map(v => v < 100 ? [v, 100] : [100, v]),
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="90"></canvas>
```